# Cartodb SQL: ST_MakeLine Conversion

Tags: sql, cartodb

I am using Cartodb to map some GPS points that I would like to connect the unique IDs with lines. I was using this [site](https://lifewatch.inbo.be/blog/posts/cartodb-tracking-data-tutorial.html) as a reference when writing my SQL. The SQL executes without any errors, but my map is not generating.

Here is my CSV dataset I'm running the SQL on:

```
X           Y         track_fid       track_seg_point_id    time
-87.5999    41.7083     0              0                   2/17/2018 16:10
-87.74214   41.91581    0              0                   2/17/2018 16:11
-87.6005    41.7081     0              0                   2/17/2018 16:14
-87.6584    41.8265     0              1                   2/17/2018 16:41
-87.63029   41.85842    0              1                   2/17/2018 16:59
-87.7308    41.8893     0              1                   2/17/2018 17:07
-87.59857   41.708393   0              2                   2/17/2018 17:08
-87.5995    41.7081     0              2                   2/17/2018 17:15
-87.68106   41.799088   0              2                   2/17/2018 17:47
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator ORDER BY time ASC) AS the_geom_webmercator,
    extract(hour from time) as hour,
    track_seg_point_id AS cartodb_id


    FROM snow_plow_data

    GROUP BY
    track_seg_point_id,
    hour
```

Here is the resulting table from my SQL:

```
Hour       cartodb_id
16         0
16         1
17         1
17         2
```

Any ideas or suggested would be great on why my map points are not being displayed as lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using BUILDER UI, you can add [`Create Lines from Points` analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/create-lines-from-points/), ordering by `time` and grouping your lines by the `track_fid` field (or `track_seg_point_id`, don't know which field you want to use):

[image: connect-with-lines]

On the other hand, if you want to do it using the SQL console. CARTO BUILDER now needs not only the `cartodb_id` and `the_geom_webmercator`, but also `the_geom` column. So you would need to add this last field to your query. Something like this should work:

```
WITH lines as (
  SELECT 
      ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator ORDER BY time ASC) AS the_geom_webmercator,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as cartodb_id
  FROM 
      tracks
  GROUP BY
      track_seg_point_id)

SELECT
    ST_Transform(the_geom_webmercator, 4326) as the_geom,
    *
FROM
    lines
```

[image: sql-lines]

Comment: Hi @ramiroaznar thank you for your response. The SQL you gave ran successfully, but it returns a table of a column of `the_geom` and `cartodb_id`. Also all the values for `the_geom` column are null

Comment: Your first answer worked though the `Create Lines from Points`, Thank you!

Comment: Hi @ramiroaznar I'm trying you SQL answer, but the_geom column is resulting in `null`, would you know why?

Comment: Can you post another question with the exact query you are applying and a link to your dataset?